# Cluster by distance between a lot off point in R

Tags: r, hierarchical-clustering, delaunay

I need to create clusters from the distance between clients if the distance between the points is less than certain precise value group them together.

I thought about using Delaunay but I'm not having success

Comment: I think you should have a look at the Stack Overflow Help Center, specifically the section [On Asking](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). From what you've posted here, I am 80% sure that the problem is your code, your data, or both, but there's still a 20% chance that you're just having installation issues. You haven't given us very much to go on...

Comment: By the content of your question, your question seems more appropriate to [Cross Validated](https://stats.stackexchange.com/). But beforehand, try to make Random Forest unsupervised and see if it suits you.